# In dynamic sql how to check the date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to check the date in dynamic sql?

I used the following ways

```
select * from master 
where Date='+convert(varchar,@dDate)+' or '+convert(varchar,@dDate)+'='null''
```

If the date is null then it has to written all the records else the records with that date.

Comment: which db are you using?

Comment: is the Date column datatype not datetime? if it is why are you converting @dDate to varchar.

Comment: what is declaration if @dDate param?

Comment: where @dDate is passed date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this

```
SET Sql = 'where a.Date > ''' + cast(@InvoiceDate as varchar(100)) + ''''
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @sql = '
    SELECT *
    FROM master
    WHERE Date IS NULL 
          OR Date = @Date
';

SET @Parameters = '
    @Date AS datetime
';

sp_executesql @sql, @Parameters, @Date
```